# jquery search problem. all forms are showing

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

all forms are showing.. I want just that `#google-search` to be active on page load. Thank you

```
 $(".header-search-input").keyup(function() {
     $(".header-search-input").val($(this).val());
 });

 var $searchByLinks = $("#search-by > a");

 $searchByLinks.click(function() {
     var $el = $(this)
     $(".header-search-form").hide();
     $($el.attr("href")).show();
     $searchByLinks.removeClass("cur-search");
     $el.addClass("cur-search");
     return false;
 });


    <div id="search-by">

     <a class="cur-search" href="#google-search">Google</a> 
     <a href="#image-search">Images</a> 
     <a href="#youtube-search">Youtube</a> 
     <a href="#maps-search">Maps</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this should work to hide all links that aren't represented by the class-name 'cur-search':

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('#search-by a:not(".cur-search")').hide();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aZUgw/](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aZUgw/).

Or, alternatively, if you don't know the specific class of the element to not-hide:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('#search-by a').not(':contains(Google)').hide();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aZUgw/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/aZUgw/1/).

---

Assuming that it's only the *first* form element you want to show, you can use:

```
$('form:gt(0)').hide();
```

Which uses [`gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt/), as I suspect is obvious, to hide all `form` elements with an index greater than 0.

[JS Fiddle demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gnbkS/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gnbkS/3/).

Or, alternatively, you could use this:

```
$('form').each(
    function(){
        var curForm = $('.cur-search').attr('href').substr(1);
        if (this.id != curForm) {
          $(this).hide();  
        }
    });
```

Which is a bit messy, but finds which `form` you want to show (based on the link with the `cur-search` class), and then iterates through all the forms to work out which to show and hides the others.

[JS Fiddle demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gnbkS/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gnbkS/4/).

Comment: no its not working here is the link to the site.. www.pocetna.net thank you very much for helping

Comment: The JS Fiddle suggests that id *does* work. If you could post a representative sample of your code to [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) I'll take a look for you. Incidentally, your page doesn't validate: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.pocetna.net/&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: its validate now. :) look here http://jsfiddle.net/gnbkS/1/  i want to show only google for first.. but on your example the menu disapers too, only google shown..

Comment: So...on page-load you want the google-search `input` element to be showing? (But keeping all the other options ('images', 'youtube' and 'maps') visible?)

Comment: yes. the input showing for google.. and options youtube, images and maps. the search is like the one in css-tricks.com on the right top

Comment: Excellent! ...in which case I'll be wearing my [underwear on the outside](http://www.comicvine.com/news/off-my-mind-why-do-heroes-wear-their-underwear-on-the-outside/141049/) for the next few hours! =p

Comment: hahaha. i have an another question about my site.. after i validated my html and css. now the opacity is not working.. how do i add it to jquery? schould i start a new question or?

Comment: solved.. little problems with ie7 but its okay.. thank you David

Comment: @zubak, a new question would be best, I think; valid (x)html shouldn't normally prevent opacity from working; so it suggests an error somewhere else.